Ansible project update is failing with error Database Error Saving Job Event
I have ansible in a cluster environment and first server ok the cluster is used for project update, all off a sudden in few days I see that project update is failed with no error in the ansible job output and in "callback-receiver.log" and I can see below:
2024-06-13 04:15:04,865 DEBUG    [-] awx.main.commands.run_callback_receiver ProjectUpdateEvent.objects.bulk_create(1)
2024-06-13 04:15:04,871 ERROR    [-] awx.main.commands.run_callback_receiver Database Error Saving Job Event
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/awx/main/dispatch/worker/callback.py", line 130, in flush
    cls.objects.bulk_create(events)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 474, in bulk_create
    ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1202, in _batched_insert
    inserted_id = self._insert(
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1377, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/lib/ol-automation-manager/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ValueError: A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.

to resolve the issue I restarted ansible but it did not work. Then I took reboot of the server and then the issue is resolved for few days and again I see the same issue

I had the same issue and I am trying to reproduce this bug can you please provide more details about your case so we can debug together
from what I understood when you source from a Git project that has a plugin which contains a NULL value (prints NULL to stdout), my problem is that the project and inventory syncs successfully even though I found same issue in the log file
